# Where install apps downloaded in tar.gz

Tags: software-installation

I am came from Windows world and have a question about place to install applications. Some applications download to my Ubuntu desktop in `tar.gz` archives. I understand I can put these apps to any location. However, maybe there is a ideologically right place. For example, some apps installs to directories: `/opt/`, `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/local/bin/`. What should I prefer?

Comment: The question that I've marked as duplicate has good advice on this topic. It's worth being aware that packages that come as a tarball rather than from the Ubuntu repositories may not have the same level of safety checking though.